# Live webcam feed

Tags: webapp-rec

Are there any websites where I can setup up a live webcam feed that can be password protected so that only I can view it?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used http://www.ustream.tv before.

When creating your "show", there is an option in the advanced tab for requiring passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Most standalone IP cameras provide such website by themselves. If you have a webcam that works only through the computer, I doubt such thing will be possible without having some service running on your machine.